# Binomial Thoerem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In the expansion of $(1+x)^n$ according to the ascending powers of $x $ if $$T_3 = 17 , 3T_2 \times T_4 = 544$$
Find the value of each n and x 
My turn 
$$\frac{n \times nC_3}{nC_2} x^{n-2}=\frac{32}{3}$$
$$n(n-2) x^{n-2}= 32$$
I stopped here because i could not solve this equation ?

Comment: What is $$T_1$$ here $$\binom n0$$  or $$\binom n1 x$$

Comment: What is stopping you for $n(n-2)x^{n-2}=32$? For $n=4$ we have $4\cdot 2\cdot x^2=32$, hence $x^2=4$.

Comment: Does it have a unique solution ?@ Dietrich Burde